# Max length of signal in gpio

Tags: hardware, raspberry-pi2

What's the maximum length across a single core wire will a high signal last on a raspberry pi GPIO pin?

I.e if I have a 3 metre signal core wire attached to a relay when the raspberry pi sends the high signal will it reach the wire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the current is low the wire resistance won't have any significant influence and you can have a very long wire. Of course, resistance is not all and inductance and capacitance will also rise and will take a toll on the high frequences. Short answer for the relay case: don't worry. The question here is if you are driving the relay directly and in that case if the gpio has anough current available.

Comment: From a raspberry pi operating at 5v it should be fine yes? Cheers

Comment: The gpio is 3.3V, you'll need a transistor (or mosfet) to drive the relay if the ralay is a 5V one.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research online and found out some guys have used a Cat5 connected to gpio which works well because the cable is designed for distance and protection from interference.

Ref here:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93455/creating-jumper-leads-from-ethernet-cables-connect-multiple-components

And nice blog on it here:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93455/creating-jumper-leads-from-ethernet-cables-connect-multiple-components